# How to fill numpy array by row and column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to fill the first and the last row and the first and the last column of a grid with `4`.

**Input:**

```
grid = np.zeros((5, 5))
[[   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]]
```

**output:**

```
[[   4.   4.   4.   4.   4. ]
 [   4.   0.   0.   0.   4. ]
 [   4.   0.   0.   0.   4. ]
 [   4.   0.   0.   0.   4. ]
 [   4.   4.   4.   4.   4. ]]
```

I tried to do this with a for loop but is there a better option than that?

Answer (score 2):

To change the values of first and last rows:

```
grid[[0,-1],:] = 4
```

To change the values of first and last columns:

```
grid[:, [0,-1]] = 4
```